# Command-line editing and wrapping

Tags: input, postgresql, libedit

When entering long queries into the command-line `psql`, my terminal[1] is not wrapping the input line correctly. Additional charactes wrap back to the left of the screen, but on the same line as the existing text, and further editing is difficult. How can I enable multi-line editing in `psql`?

Mutli-line editing in bash via SSH wraps correcty, so this is related to `psql` specifically.

For reference:

```
$ psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 8.4.21
contains support for command-line editing
```

This is unrelated to using screen/byobu? When I launch `psql` outside of screen/byobu. it displays multi-line inputs somewhat better (they now span multiple lines), but editing is still not possible due to incorrect positioning of the cursor.

I experienced similar difficulties editing long input lines when using iTerm2 with and without screen/byobu.

In both cases, the terminals were set to default value for emulation (xterm-256color).

I experienced the same difficulties using xfce4-terminal in Xubuntu in a VirtualBox.

I experienced the same difficulties using PuTTY from a Microsoft Windows Vista computer.

Has `psql` ever handled multi-line editing correclty? I've used it for years and have never experienced this difficuty before ...

[1] Terminal.app in Apple Mac OS X Mavericks, with a secure shell session to an Ubuntu server running bash.

Comment: `psql` uses `libedit` (a BSD thing, ironic that it wouldn't work on OS/X), not `readline` (a GNU thing).

Comment: This seems variable, as this page states that `psql` can be compiled with `readline`: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/app-psql.html

Comment: OK, I stand corrected, so what is it for you (I suppose if bash works, it's probably not readline)? `ldd /usr/lib/postgresql/*/bin/psql | grep -e libedit -e readline`

Comment: `libedit.so.2 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libedit.so.2 (0xb75f2000)`
`libedit.so.2 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libedit.so.2 (0xb76f9000)`

Comment: It might help to compare the output of `infocmp` on OS/X and Ubuntu. What's `$TERM`? Does it work better with `TERM=Apple_Terminal`?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: `psql` in Ubuntu *is* linked against `libedit`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was related to the `psql` prompt, as set in the `.psqlrc` file. Renaming this file and restarting `psql` solved the problem.

Comment: I have used this prompt for a number of years, without any difficulties editing command line input. Possibly an update to psql and/or libedit resulted in this.

Comment: What was that prompt? Maybe that can be reported as a bug to postgresql/libedit.

Comment: `\set PROMPT1 '%[%033[1;33m%]%/%[%033[32m%]%R%#%[%33[0m%] '
`

`\set PROMPT2 '%[%033[1;33m%]%/%[%033[31m%]%R%#%[%33[0m%] '`